# Custom UICollectionViewCell not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a storyboard and my custom UICollectionViewCell is not appearing. I played around with it for a few hours and have googled a ton of different solutions but none worked. Just to clarify, the data exists, and the UICollectionView is appearing, but the cell is not. Here is my code. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)mutualFriendsView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.resultsDictionary count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)mutualFriendsView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"PCRRequesterMutualFriendsCollectionViewCell";

PCRRequesterMutualFriendsCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.mutualFriendsView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSArray *idArray = [self.resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
NSArray *nameArray = [self.resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.profileName.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)mutualFriendsView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"cell #%d was selected", indexPath.row);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
[mutualFriendsView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

BOOL retVal = YES;
return retVal;
}
```

**EDIT** Here is my viewDidLoad

```
self.mutualFriendsView.dataSource = self;
self.mutualFriendsView.delegate = self;

self.mutualFriendsView.pagingEnabled = YES;

//    [self.mutualFriendsView registerClass:[PCRMutualFriendsCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PCRMutualFriendsCollectionViewCell"];
```

**Edit** I think I figured out the problem. I don't think the dictionary is being populated after the completion block finishes. Any suggestions for saving the value of the dictionary from the block to be used outside of it?

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *mutualFriends = nil;

__block NSNumber *total;

NSString *u = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.details[@"Requester"][@"profile"][@"facebookId"]];
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:(@"/%@", u)
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          if (!error){
                              NSLog(@"RESULT OF FB %@", result);
                              if (result == nil){
                                  NSLog(@"No shared friends");
                              } else {
                                  total = result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"summary"][@"total_count"];
                                  NSLog(@"TOTAL FRIENDS %@", total);
                                  for(int i=0;i<[result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"] count];i++)
                                  {
                                      mutualFriends = result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"][i];


                                      NSLog(@"FRIENDDATA %@", mutualFriends);
                                  }

                              }


                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
                          }

                      }];



self.resultsDictionary = mutualFriends;
self.number = total;
NSLog(@"NUMBER %@", self.number);
NSLog(@"RESULTS DICTIONARY %@", self.resultsDictionary);
NSString *friends = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have %@ friends in common including:", self.number];
```

Comment: Is the cellForItemAtIndexPath method getting called at all?

Comment: just checked - its not. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: There should be a method that supplies the number of sections in the collection. If that is returning 0 then the number or items method will not be called. Also, when is resultsDictionary getting populated? If it is after viewDidLoad you will probably need to call collectionView.reloadData() after the resultsDictionary is populated.

Comment: I just added in the following and its still not getting called. Also the resultDictionary is being populated in the viewDidLoad.       -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)mutualFriendsView
{
    return 1;

}

Comment: Try putting a collectionView.reloadData() at the end of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Just added that in and its still not getting called. Do you think I should uncomment the registerClass method?

Comment: Just tried that. No difference.

Comment: Can you check and see if self.mutualFriendsView is actually wired up to the collection view that is being displayed. If you've used a view created by IB it will automatically write the collection view to a property in the base UICollectionViewController class, surprisingly called collectionView.  It just seems like something fundamental like that isn't happening.

Comment: As I wrote in my most recent edit, the error seems to be that dictionary is not being populated with the values from the completion block. I don't think the dictionary has enough time to populate once the because the completion block is called after the view gets loaded. Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<[result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"] count];i++)
{
   mutualFriends = result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"][i];
   NSLog(@"FRIENDDATA %@", mutualFriends);
}
// add
self.resultsDictionary = mutualFriends;
mutualFriendsView.reloadData();
```

All within that completion block. So when FB finally does return and you've accumulated all the mutualFriends, then you tell the collectionView to reload.

Comment: I got the following error with that _Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PCRMutualFriendsCollectionViewCell 0x16f8f370> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key profileName.'_

Comment: Well, that's a step in the right direction, it's trying to load a cell now. Okay, so that means that the XIB you're loading is trying to wire up an outlet to an undefined property. This usually happens if you've specified the wrong class in Custom Class-Class field in IB. That's the 3rd icon from the left in the property inspector. If you didn't change it that class name is probably UICollectionViewCell when it should be PCRMutualFriendsCollectionViewCell

Comment: I messed around with it and ultimately ended up creating a new nsobject with a custom initializer and setting the cell's contents to the object and passing the object info from the block. Not the most efficient way of doing things but, it finally works. thanks for all of the help!